# How to Use Gradle Wrapper in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

[image]    Error:(12, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':Application'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\Android\SwipeRefreshListFragment\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

This problem arise during Gradle Sync ....

Comment: Read the error...? `try editing the distributionUrl in D:\Android\SwipeRefreshListFragment\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: What is unclear with the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the path for gradle directory from gradle-2.8 to gradle-2.10

Steps:

Click on file ->settings ->gradle

Choose "Use local gradle distribution" radio button in the project-level setting

open and paste the path of the directory of gradle-2.10

( Note : Path will be similar to where gradle-2.8 was earlier present if you have done any update for android studio, or else you have to mention the path of download directory if you have downloaded the standalone gradle distribution from http://gradle.org/gradle-download/ )

change the gradle 2.8 to gradle 2.10 in file ->settings ->gradle

Apply the settings and rebuild the project.

Comment: _ i install the latest gradle version and change from "use local gradle distribution" but still error ..._

Comment: > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your directory structure ?